# What System.Windows UIElement does skype use for its 'Contact List'?

Tags: c#, wpf, user-interface, skype, uielement

Hey so I was wondering what `UIElement` does skype use for its `Contact List` in order to display additional details within each `ListItem` (such as `Status Updates`, `Avatars`, `Online Status` and so forth)?

[image: skype list box]
<sub>(source: [iforce.co.nz](http://iforce.co.nz/i/bckdwlmw.aym.png))</sub>

As far as I know the regular `System.Windows.Forms.ListBox` only lets you display a single line of text to represent that `Object`.

[image: windows.form.listbox]
<sub>(source: [iforce.co.nz](http://iforce.co.nz/i/sfcfdepr.ujc.png))</sub>

I'm looking to recreate something similar but for a different purpose, but I haven't been able to find much on google (So that's why I'm seeing if anyone here has experience modifying the design of a `ListBox`, to gain a better perspective over each detail).

Thanks

Comment: Are you positively, absolutely *sure* Skype uses WPF on your platform?

Comment: I'm not sure, that's why I'm asking. I think it might be possible? but in reality I'm not sure.

Comment: @Killrawr: 1. It's Delphi 2. It's definitely a custom control. It's actually not rare when you implement custom controls, especially when you're a skype programmer

Comment: It's not about "modifying the design" at all, it's about implementing a completely new control from the scratch.

Comment: You can just create your own `ListBoxItem` that has images and lables anywhere you want, Very simple, what example are you looking for WPF or Winforms, I don't mind mocking one up

Comment: If you have less time and more cash, get some third party controls.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a very basic example of creating a custom `Datatemplate` for WPF.

First you create your `Model` with all the properties you want to be displayed, then bind a list of them to your `ListBox`. Then you can create a `DataTemplate` this is basically a xaml(visual) representation of your `Model`, you can make it look however you want and you can use any of the properties from your `Model` in the `DataTemplate`.

Example:

Window code:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private ObservableCollection<MyListBoxItemModel> _listBoxItems = new ObservableCollection<MyListBoxItemModel>();

    public MainWindow()
    { 
        InitializeComponent();
        ListBoxItems.Add(new MyListBoxItemModel { Title = "Item 1", Image = new BitmapImage(new Uri("http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/custom-icon-design/mini/32/Search-icon.png")) });
        ListBoxItems.Add(new MyListBoxItemModel { Title = "Item 2", Image = new BitmapImage(new Uri("http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/custom-icon-design/mini/32/Search-icon.png")) });
        ListBoxItems.Add(new MyListBoxItemModel { Title = "Item 3", Image = new BitmapImage(new Uri("http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/custom-icon-design/mini/32/Search-icon.png")) });
    }

    public ObservableCollection<MyListBoxItemModel> ListBoxItems
    {
        get { return _listBoxItems; }
        set { _listBoxItems = value; }
    }
}
```

Model:

```
public class MyListBoxItemModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _title;
    private string _line2 = "Line2";
    private BitmapImage _image;

    public string Title
    {
        get { return _title; }
        set { _title = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("Title"); }
    }

    public string Line2
    {
        get { return _line2; }
        set { _line2 = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("Line2"); }
    }


    public BitmapImage Image
    {
        get { return _image; }
        set { _image = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("Image"); }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string p)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(p));
        }
    }
}
```

Xaml:

```
   <Window x:Class="WpfApplication7.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication7"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="351" Width="464" Name="UI" >

 <Window.Resources>
    <!-- The tempate for MyListBoxItemModel -->
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:MyListBoxItemModel}">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Image Source="{Binding Image}" />
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" FontWeight="Medium" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Line2}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>   
 </Window.Resources>

    <Grid>
        <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=UI, Path=ListBoxItems}" />
    </Grid>

</Window>
```

This is just a simple example with an `Image` and some text, but it should get you started, Just modify the `DataTemplate` and `Model` how you want to display the `snp code` data

Result:

[image]

Comment: Hey thanks, do you have any idea on how to add a `<LineBreak />` in the `Text=""` Setter?

Comment: What do you mean by LineBreak? NewLine? you could just add a new TextBlocl or use a MutiBinding on the existing TextBlock

Comment: do you mind updating the answer with an example using a `MultiBinding`? (To display a an item for example `Item 2.1` Underneth `Item 2`). Thanks again! :)

Comment: Updated Datatemplate and Model to show MultiBinding on TextBlock

Comment: Hey sa_ddam213, Thank you so much. I was wondering how do you seperate the styling between `Item 2` and `Item 2.1`?

Comment: What do you mean? if you want diffent styles (Font etc) you should make each one its own TextBlock and style as you wish, The MultiBinding will just join the strings together

Comment: I mean `Item 2` could be `FontWeight="Medium"` while `Item 2.1` stays `Normal`.

Comment: Then they will have to be 2 seperate TextBlocks, I have updated the Datatemplate in the answer to show this.